# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to create a pagination script but it appears that the following lines are not working causing the page to not load.

```
 $limit = 20;

$start_from = ($page - 1) * $limit;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT :startf, :limits");
$stmt->bindValue(":startf", $start_from, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(":limits", $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

The error I am getting is

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: *SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax*

I have been trying to fix it by changing bindParam to bindValue, adding PDO::PARAM_INT but it will not fix.

Thanks,
Ben J

Comment: maybe you get some negative values for variables of `LIMIT`. Have you tried to print them ( `:startf`,`:limits` ) out ?

Comment: You need to check your variable values

Comment: I did get a negative value now that I remember. It was a -20

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you get some negative values for variables `:startf` and `:limits` of `LIMIT` clause.

> a ***LIMIT*** clause that is used to specify the number of records to
>   return, and those (*both two of them in your case*) are *non-negative integer* values.

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/467d5f/6)

Comment: How would I go about fixing this, I returned a -20 value

Comment: @Policeboy109 perhaps, you may replace value of $page with 1, when it's 0.

Comment: please look at my demo and try to print the returned values of the parameters

Comment: I don't quite understand

Comment: Ah, if I set $start_from to 1 and $limit to 2 it doesn't show an error but doesn't exactly work as it isn't dynamic